# Confusion over map vs. flatMap: Cannot invoke 'flatMap' with an argument list of type '(() -> EventLoopFuture)'

Tags: swift, future, vapor

I'm a Swift beginner, working in the Vapor framework, developing a signup process which requires several steps in series to work. I'm encountering an issue with the following code, which Xcode indicates an error exists on the marked line:

```
func signup(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<RecordA> {
    return try req.content.decode(RecordACreation.self).flatMap(to: RecordACreation.self) { recordACreation in

        // Prevent a recordA email from being used twice.
        RecordA(on: req).filter(\.email == recordACreation).first().map(to: RecordA.self) { optionalExistingRecordAByEmail in
            if let _ = optionalExistingRecordAByEmail {
                throw Abort(.unprocessableEntity, reason: "RecordA email already exists")
            }

        }.flatMap { // Xcode indicates there's an error here.
            // Prevent an recordB email from being used twice.
            return RecordB.query(on: req).filter(\.email == recordACreation.recordBEmail).first().map(to: RecordA.self) { optionalExistingRecordBByEmail in
                if let _ = optionalExistingRecordBByEmail {
                    throw Abort(.unprocessableEntity, reason: "RecordB email already exists.")
                }
            }

        }.flatMap {
            // If the recordB's password could not be successfully hashed.
            guard let recordBPassword = try? BCrypt.hash(recordACreation.recordBPassword) else {
                throw Abort(.unprocessableEntity, reason: "Password was unhashed")
            }

            // Ensure a verification token is generated successfully.
            guard let optionalVerificationToken = try? VerificationTokenService.generate(), let verificationToken = optionalVerificationToken else {
                throw Abort(.unprocessableEntity, reason: "Verification token could not be generated.")
            }

            let recordA = RecordA(name: recordACreation.recordAName, email: recordACreation.recordAEmail)

            return req.transaction(on: .sqlite) { conn in
                // TODO: Send email on signup success.

                return recordA.save(on: conn).map(to: RecordA.self) { savedRecordA in
                    guard let recordAId = recordA.id else {
                        throw Abort(.unprocessableEntity, reason: "Verification token could not be generated.")
                    }

                    _ = RecordB(name: recordACreation.recordBName, email: recordACreation.recordBEmail, password: recordBPassword, recordAId: recordAId, verificationToken: verificationToken).save(on: conn)
                    return savedRecordA
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error reads:

> Cannot invoke 'flatMap' with an argument list of type '(() -> EventLoopFuture)'

I don't entirely understand the mechanisms between an appropriate selection of `map` and `flatMap`, so that may be the cause of the issue here. Thoughts?

Comment: For any sequence: `map` works with function that takes value of type of element of the sequence and returns value of different type that gets wrapped into sequence; `flatMap` takes value of type of element of the sequence and returns another sequence, elements from which gets rewrapped into combined sequence.

Comment: It seems that `query` works asynchronously. You cannot use asynchronous tasks in a `flatMap` closure.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the `map` call after the `RecordA` query:

```swift
RecordA(on: req).filter(\.email == recordACreation).first().map(to: RecordA.self) { optionalExistingRecordAByEmail in
    if let _ = optionalExistingRecordAByEmail {
        throw Abort(.unprocessableEntity, reason: "RecordA email already exists")
    }
}
```

You are passing in `RecordA.self` to the `to` parameter, which sets the return type for the closure to `RecordA`. Instead you aren't returning anything. You should remove the `to` parameter and it should work:

```swift
RecordA(on: req).filter(\.email == recordACreation).first().map { optionalExistingRecordAByEmail in
    if let _ = optionalExistingRecordAByEmail {
        throw Abort(.unprocessableEntity, reason: "RecordA email already exists")
    }
}
```